# Generic Inquiry Condition

Tags: acumatica

I can't get conditions to work in generic inquiry for date fields if doing anything except an `"equals"`.   Just want to filter query by date range.  Anyone have an example of syntax? Can I use `builtin conditions` (`less than`, `greater than`, etc) or do I need to uncheck `"from schema"` and do some sort of expression?

Answer (score 0):

we use as below and it is working correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Conditions tab should reference the parameter in the way highlighted in this standard GI (which you can find in any SalesDemo) company. You basically need 4 rows, 2 for each Start and End date.
[image]